# how can i make eyes follow the cursor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

like this by action script 3 
http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/flash/movingeyes

Comment: note this tutorial made by action script 2 and i want to make it by action script3 , thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.zebra0.com/flash/pdf/Eyes.pdf

http://www.flashkit.com/tutorials/Math-Physics/Creating-Andrew_S-738/index.php

http://www.ruclip.com/video/bOMPDxZqnrc/flash-8-eyes-moving-tutorial.html

http://www.riacodes.com/flash/eyes-follow-the-cursor/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XftKp6FPfyY

Answer (score 4):

That page you linked to is a tutorial on how to do it.

Just click on begin to view the tutorial.

Comment: i want to make it by action script3

Comment: it made in the tutorial by action script2